# Linear Minimum Mean Squared Error Estimate (LMMSE) predictor for an MA(3) process

Tags: self-study, independence, predictor, moving-average, white-noise

A moving average (MA) process is described by

$X[n]=\sum_{k=0}^{L}d_kW_{n-k}$

Such a process is denoted MA(L) and is said to be of order L. The input W[n] is an independent random sequence.

Find theoretically the best Linear Minimum Mean Squared Estimate (LMMSE) predictor for an MA(3) process

$x_n=d_0w_n+d_1w_{n-1}+d_2w_{n-2}+d_3w_{n-3}$

where the coefficients are

$[d_0,d_1,d_2,d_3]=[2,1,2,1]$

and the input W[n] to the MA(3) filter is white Gaussian noise with mean zero and variance 3, that is, $W_n\epsilon N(0,3)$. The predictor should use the three latest values of the process to predict the next value, that is

$\hat{X}[n+1]=a_0X[n]+a_1X[n-1]+a_2X[n-2]$

My approach to this assigment is to use to define the orthogonality principle which means that the "Estimated error" is perpendicular to the "Data", with LMMSE estimation, with $\sum_{k=0}^{2}a_kX[n-k]$ we have

$
\Bigg[
\begin{matrix}
    E(X[n+1]X[n])\\
    E(X[n+1]X[n-1])\\
    E(X[n+1]X[n-2])
\end{matrix}
\Bigg]
=
\Bigg[
\begin{matrix}
    E(X[n]X[n]) & E(X[n-1]X[n]) & E(X[n-2]X[n])\\
    E(X[n]X[n-1]) & E(X[n-1]X[n-1]) & E(X[n-1]X[n-1])\\
    E(X[n]X[n-2]) & E(X[n-1]X[n-1]) & E(X[n-2]X[n-1])
\end{matrix}
\Bigg]
\Bigg[
\begin{matrix}
a_0\\
a_1\\
a_2
\end{matrix}
\Bigg]
=
\Bigg[
\begin{matrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{matrix}
\Bigg]
$

Substituting for above expression yield

$
\Bigg[
\begin{matrix}
    R_{XX}(1)\\
    R_{XX}(2)\\
    R_{XX}(3)
\end{matrix}
\Bigg]
=
\Bigg[
\begin{matrix}
    R_{XX}(0) & R_{XX}(1) & R_{XX}(2)\\
    R_{XX}(1) & R_{XX}(0) & R_{XX}(1)\\
    R_{XX}(2) & R_{XX}(1) & R_{XX}(0)
\end{matrix}
\Bigg]
\Bigg[
\begin{matrix}
a_0\\
a_1\\
a_2
\end{matrix}
\Bigg]$

According to a friend this expression should be equal to

$
\Bigg[
\begin{matrix}
    6\\
    5\\
    4
\end{matrix}
\Bigg]
=
\Bigg[
\begin{matrix}
    10 & 6 & 5\\
    6 & 10 & 6\\
    5 & 6 & 10
\end{matrix}
\Bigg]
\Bigg[
\begin{matrix}
a_0\\
a_1\\
a_2
\end{matrix}
\Bigg]$

where $R_{XX}(3)=4$ is just a guess since I don't know where the other values come from but according to my friend they are suppose to be correct. Can somebody please explain where the values for $R_{XX}(0)$,$R_{XX}(1)$ and $R_{XX}(2)$ comes from and also I am curious how to calculate $R_{XX}(3)$?

Comment: What are MMSE and LMMSE? Is this in discrete time? Then it would be more conventional to use subscripts like $W_n$ rather than $W[n]$. Also, if this is a homework exercise, please tag it as [`self-study`](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: I think that if you don't understand what autocovariances are and how you calculate them, it would be worthwhile to revisit this topic. Otherwise this question will not make much sense.

Comment: @KristofferJerzyLinder No, I definitely mean autocovariance. Your $R_{XX}(h)$ terms are the autocovariances of the process $X[t]$. Thus, to answer your question in full: $R_{XX}(m)=Cov(X[t], X[t-m])$. I don't understand why you are patronizing, I honestly mean that to solve this exercise you need to know what autocovariances are because that is the answer to your question...! If you know that, calculating $R_{XX}(3)$ is very simple, you just compute a covariance. Given that, you are just matrix inversion and a multiplication away from finding your coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

The correlation coefficients are actually obtained by calculating the expectation values for $X[n]$,$X[n-1]$,$X[n-2]$, this is easily done by expressing everything in terms of $W[n]$,$W[n-1]$ and so on. The $X[n]$ term is already given so for $R_{XX}(0)=E(X[n]X[n])$ we have

\begin{equation}
R_{XX}(0)=E((d_0w[n]+d_1w[n-1]+d_2w[n-2]+d_3w[n-3])^2)
\end{equation}

Now when expanding the parenthesis it is very important to remember that all products of $w[n]$ with different indexes vanish, for example $w[n]w[n-1]=0$. This leaves us with the terms

\begin{equation}
R_{XX}(0)=E(d_0^2w[n]w[n]+d_1^2w[n-1]w[n-1]+d_2^2w[n-2]w[n-2]+d_3^2w[n-3]w[n-3])
\end{equation}

Here the expectations values for $w^2[n]...w^2[n-3]$ are equal to 1 so we have

\begin{equation}
R_{XX}(0)=d_0^2+d_1^2+d_2^2+d_3^2=4+1+4+1=10
\end{equation}

The same yields for the other correlation coefficients